# Powershell to get all TFS Workspaces

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfs-2015

I am trying to get a list of all workspaces created on my TFS server. I have tried:

```
 #if no collection specified, open project picker to select it via gui
$picker = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamProjectPicker([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamProjectPickerMode]::NoProject, $false)
$dialogResult = $picker.ShowDialog()
if ($dialogResult -ne "OK")
{
    exit
}
$tfs = $picker.SelectedTeamProjectCollection
$tfs.EnsureAuthenticated()
$vcs = $tfs.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer]);

$wss = $vcs.QueryWorkspaces($null, $null, $null);
```

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb138991(v=vs.120).aspx) implies that if I pass all NULL's as parameters then it should pull all Workspaces... I get nothing back...

I am a Collection Administrator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use `[System.Management.Automation.Language.NullString]::Value` instead of `$null` for the first parameter.